# How to disable let's encrypt ssl and install commercial ssl

Tags: nginx, ssl-certificate, lets-encrypt, ubuntu-18.04

I'm running https://lyfcure.com on nginx Ubuntu 18.04..

I installed let's encrypt ssl certificate to my domain. Now I want to disable it and install a commercial ssl certificate...

Please, help me...To disable the let's encrypt ssl.

I was followed this liNk to install ssl- https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-nginx-with-let-s-encrypt-on-ubuntu-18-04

Comment: Looks like you got it working. Why, though? Let's Encrypt is a far more reputable vendor than GoDaddy, and it's *free* too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

open your nginx configuration file and point ssl_certificate* to your commercial ssl